# Duplicate ALL Filemaker Portal Rows only if valid

Tags: filemaker

I would like to create a script that copies only valid Portal Rows from a Record.

ie. Sample Request is the main record
    Sample colours are the relationship (SampleNumberID)
    ie. Colour 1, Colour 2, Colour 3, Colour 4

I can get this for work if it has all 4 rows entered, however if there is ok 2 colour entries It will copy it twice to fill up 4 portals every time.

Any help would be great, Thanks.

Image of Current Script working for 4 colour ways however if only 1 colour is entered it will copy the same colour 4 times.

http://www.coquet.com.au/wp-content/Script.png

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it, I would go to the related records, using the portal row relationship. Go to the first record, loop through them all and duplicate each one and then return to the parent record. So it would look something like this:

```
Go to Related Record [Show only related records; From table: "Sample Request"]
Go to Record/Request/Page [First]
Loop
    Duplicate Record/Request []
    Set Field [ByCoulor::StyleNumberID; GetNextSerialValue(Get(FileName); "Sample Request")]
    Go to Record/Request/Page [Next; Exit after last]
End Loop
Go to Layout [original layout]
```

As a side note, it looks like you might to set the field StyleNumberID as an Auto-Enter serial number, so you don't have to manually set it.